# Anaconda doesn't install

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I got an error downloading Anaconda. Let me explain step by step :

- I download windows 64 bits installer (I'm on win 10)
- I launch the exe
- I follow the steps, don't do anything, just accept and run it
- It says "space required : 3Gb, space disponible : 41Gb"
- It installs Anaconda really fast
- When I start _conda.exe, the only exe (with the uninstaller), a cmd appears,writes some lines and closes. Just that, nothing else.

My Anaconda 3 folder says "466Mb", not 3Gb at all... Coincidence ?
My installer weights also 466Mb... Did it just extract the installer or something ?

Guys on other forums that have Anaconda told me I got less than half of the files. How could I download it properly ? Where is the problem located ? The computer ? The installer ? Something else ?
I already got python and Sublime Text, and in the installer, there are options with path etc... I didn't touch that but maybe the error comes from here ?

Thank you so much if you can help, have a nice day !

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I don't see how you can reasonably expect an answer on Stack Overflow. Problems like this are completely annoying but typically idiosyncratic to your situation. How could we know if your computer has a problem or your internet connection is glitchy? It might be a problem with your antivirus software interfering. Who knows?

Comment: Try launching the installe with admin rights

Comment: It seems like a common enough problem: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8976

Comment: Sorry @desertnaut, but because Anaconda is used for machine learning, I thought tagging ml would make people with anaconda installed and knowing how to do it see my question... And maybe answering it ^^'
JohnColeman Someone who had the same problem can see this and maybe help me knowing what's happening... And thanks for your link !
Ivan I tried, nothing changed

Comment: ML people using Anaconda are a small subset of its total users. I understand your rationale, I am just kindly pointing out that this is tag abuse and should be avoided in the future. Best of luck with your question.

Comment: Of course now I'll avoid this, and thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Oooooh it worked ! Thanks to John Coleman that gave me the link ^^
It was said inside that a guy had the same problem, installed the 32-bits version and it worked... So I did same and now I got way more files and it works !

Thanks to all who answered !